# convert Reader<_, _option> to ReaderT<_, _ option>

Tags: f#+

I have a function type `Reader<_, string option>`, and I would like to use it inside a `ReaderT<_, unit option>` so that I can drill all the way into the value inside `option` with `let!` How could I do it please?

```ml
let fun1: Reader<_, string option> = // some implementation
let fun2: ReaderT< _, unit option> = monad {
  let! valueFun1 = // how do I drill through option and reader monad to get the value inside? lift and hoist?
  return ()
}
```

A working solution is to bend `fun1` to have type `ReaderT< _ , string option>` so I could seemlessly use it in `fun2`, but I don't need the extra feature of `ReaderT` in `fun1`, I'd like to keep it the most elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to unwrap the `Reader` and wrap it into a `ReaderT`:

```ml
#r "nuget: FSharpPlus"

open FSharpPlus
open FSharpPlus.Data


let fun1: Reader<int, string option> = Unchecked.defaultof<_> // some implementation

let fun2: ReaderT<int, unit option> = monad {
    let! valueFun1 = ReaderT (Reader.run fun1)
    return () }
```

Having said that, what's the purpose of having a `Reader<'R, string option>` in first place?

Unless you are going to bind the whole `string option` type, I mean without expecting the option short-circuit effect, I would skip the `Reader` wrapper.
Either keep it as a naked function, or wrap it directly to `ReaderT` if you know you'll bind with short-circuit effects later.